# What are the advantages of using with for opening files on Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, python

What are the real performance advantages of using

```
with open(__file__, 'r') as f:
```

instead of using:

```
open(__file__,'r')
```

in Python 3 for both writing and reading files?

Comment: You shouldn't use `__name__` style identifiers for common variables. Those names are intended to have special, "magic", meaning.

Comment: @ulidtko That’s how it’s used here — the module is opening itself.

Comment: read this: http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What the with statement basically does is take advantage of two new magic keywords on an object: `__enter__` and `__exit__` to implement automatic cleanup (c++ destructors, .net IDisposable, etc). So what effectively happens is as follows:

```
file = open(__file__, 'r')
try:
  # your code here
finally: file.close()
```

Feel free to read a bit more about the actual implementation in [pep-0343](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/)

Answer (score 12):

Using `with` means that the file will be closed as soon as you leave the block. This is beneficial because closing a file is something that can easily be forgotten and ties up resources that you no longer need.

Comment: Note that this isn’t specific to Python 3 at all.

Comment: @jleedev: Correct, `with` existed before Python3.

Comment: `with` was introduced in Python 2.6 but was available as early as Python 2.5 as a `__future__` feature (e.g. `from __future__ import with_statement`).

Comment: file will also be closed if any exception occurs in the with block

Comment: Does this mean that it is unnecessary to close the file when using with?

Comment: @GeorgeWillcox Correct. When using `with`, `__exit__()` calls `close()` so you don't have to do it manually.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question of what performance advantage, there is none from a strict CPU/memory standpoint.  Your code won't perform any better, but it will be more robust with less typing and it should be more clear and thus easier to maintain.  So in a sense, the performance gain will be measured in man-hours in later maintenance, which as we all should know is the true cost of software, so it will have a great "performance advantage". ;)

Answer (score 1):

with the classical syntax you have to take care of closing the file, thus even if an exception occured during file treatment.

IMHO On the other side, with the `with` statement, you are able to write smaller code, easier to read, python is taking care of closing the file after you leave the `with` block.